# Mysql limit of results?

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I have a table with approximatly 1000 records.

I have a request :

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM ophlm_ancien.patrimoine";
$result = mysql_query($select);
while($p = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //some actions
}
```

If a run my script, i have this error on firefox : `The connection was reset`

I a add a LIMIT 500, it work. LIMIT 600 too. But after i always have this error.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1):

Increase your [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html) on the server.

Comment: Probably would be wise to specify a column list too.

Comment: Yep, good point, if you don't need all columns, don't request all columns, and even if you need all columns, specifying them explicitly guarantees clear failures instead of mystical obscure ones on unexpected table changes.

Comment: @ClémentAndraud: are you having problems increasing it, or does it not work? Check the output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`.

Comment: And how big should the entire resultset be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27022/discussion-between-clement-andraud-and-wrikken)

Answer (score 0):

Up to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id1026131) you can combine the LIMIT with an offset:

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

Which lets you kind of buffer the results:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return.

All you need to do is to execute the selects in a loop and match the offset in each round until you get all results.